# Does it help perf/memory pressure to use an image loader on local resources/icons in Android?

Tags: android, image, performance, picasso

I use an image loading library (Picasso) to do image loading/display for remote images, and it works very well. However, for local resources (mostly smaller image icons) I've been simply putting the image directly in the xml (via src="@drawable/image_name").

Should I also be using Picasso (or Glide, etc) to load these smaller local images? If so, should I do so for both lists (shown via RecyclerView) and one off icons? Currently loading these local resources w/o a loader is working, but I would like to improve perf if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard practice for local density specific resources that are included with the apk is to just load them via resources, either by including them as src or background in xml or using Resources#getDrawable().

Usually an image loading library is unnecessary for local resources because local resources tend to be small, fast to decode and are frequently already in memory in the resources cache managed by Android.

That said, if you think you have a performance problem, measure! If it looks like a particular image heavy Activity or Fragment is slow to start because of layout inflation time, you may want to experiment with using an image loading library for resources. Using an image loading library is also probably appropriate if you're loading raw resources, or resources that aren't split by density.